# subprocess not working after onefile pyinstaller even with stdout/stdin defined

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess, pyinstaller, stdout

I have a tkinter GUI with a text box and run button.  Pressing the run button turns it to yellow and starts a subroutine that prints a few numbers.  Text output from the subroutine is redirected to the GUI text box.  However, after creating a standalone executable file with pyinstaller, it no longer works.  Pressing the run button doesn't seem to start the subprocess.  It does turn yellow, but no text appears in the text box and it seems to start another instance of the main program - a second GUI appears after about 10 seconds which is how long it takes for the initial GUI to appear.  The run button stays yellow on the initial GUI.

I've seen a bit online about other people having issues with subprocesses not running after pyinstaller, but most of the solutions seem to be to make sure stdout, stdin are set to subprocess.PIPE which I have, so I'm at a bit of a loss what to try next.

I'm creating my standalone with this:

```
pyinstaller --onefile simpleGUI.py
```

My subprocess file, testsubprocess.py is:

```
import time

for i in range(3):
    print("%d.%d" % divmod(i, 10))
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

My main GUI file, simpleGUI.py, is:

```
import sys
import subprocess
from threading import Thread
import tkinter as tk
from queue import Queue, Empty


def iter_except(function, exception):
    try:
        while True:
            yield function()
    except exception:
        return


class DisplaySubprocessOutputDemo:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root

        width=600
        height=350
        xloc=0
        yloc=10
        self.root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, xloc, yloc))

        self.statustext = tk.Text(self.root, height=4, width=30)
        self.statustext.grid(row=3, column=1)

        self.startbutton = tk.Button(self.root, text = 'Start', command=self.startprocess, bg='green', activebackground = 'orange')
        self.startbutton.config(height = 2, width = 15)
        self.startbutton.grid(row = 5, column=0,sticky='E')
        self.startbuttonpresses = 0
        
        exitbutton = tk.Button(self.root, text = 'Exit', command=self.quit, bg='red')
        exitbutton.config(height = 2, width = 15)
        exitbutton.grid(row = 5, column=4, sticky='E')
        
        
    def startprocess(self):    
        self.startbuttonpresses = self.startbuttonpresses+1
        
        if self.startbuttonpresses == 1:
            
            self.startbutton.configure(bg='yellow')
            self.startbutton.configure(text='Stop')
         
            self.process = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "-u", "testsubprocess.py"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    
            q = Queue(maxsize=1024)  
            t = Thread(target=self.reader_thread, args=[q])
            t.daemon = True 
            t.start()
    
            self.updatetext(q) 
            
        else:
            self.startbuttonpresses = 0
            self.process.kill()
            self.startbutton.configure(bg='green')
            self.startbutton.configure(text='Start')
            

    def reader_thread(self, q):
        try:
            with self.process.stdout as pipe:
                for line in iter(pipe.readline, b''):
                    q.put(line)
        finally:
            q.put(None)


    def updatetext(self, q):
        for line in iter_except(q.get_nowait, Empty): # display all content
            if line is None:
                self.startbuttonpresses = 0
                self.startbutton.configure(bg='green')
                self.startbutton.configure(text='Start')
                
                return
            else:
                self.statustext.insert(tk.END, line)

        self.root.after(400, self.updatetext, q) 


    def quit(self):
        try:
            self.process.kill() 
        except Exception:
            pass
        self.root.destroy()


root = tk.Tk()
app = DisplaySubprocessOutputDemo(root)
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", app.quit)
root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow %s center' % root.winfo_pathname(root.winfo_id()))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Debug stdout, stderr, returncode from `Popen`. Probably `testsubprocess.py` is not found in the current working directory

Comment: I'm running my executable from Anaconda prompt to try to get some error messages, but I get nothing - either within the GUI text box, or within the Anaconda prompt window.  Is there something I need to do to get error messages to show up?

Comment: I also tried explicitly adding the testsubprocess.py file to the build with this:  ```pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "testsubprocess.py;." simpleGUI.py```, but I get the same results

Answer (score 1):

When the process is executing with PyInstaller `sys.executable` is pointing to the exe file created and not to the python.exe like in the interpreter so the Popen will not work.

You can try to create another executable for the `testsubprocess.py` and point Popen to it or use multiprocessing (don’t forget to use freeze_support if you do https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support)

Comment: Yup - that's it!  I replaced sys.executable with the path to my python.exe and it now works.  I'll look up multiprocessing.  Thanks a lot!  I'd upvote your solution by I don't have enough points yet.